# Checking a string matches any string in a string array?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I'm looking for a way to check a string that a user inputs when prompted (let's take it to be a string variable "userinput") from an array of 10 other strings. So far I have:

```
    while (userinput.empty()) //Check for empty input
{
    cout << "Please enter your identity.\n"; //Identify user
    getline(cin, userinput);

    do //Check to see if user is the same as the string variable "user"
    {
    cout << "This user is either non existent or has access privileges revoked.\n"; //Wrong username!
    cout << "Please re-enter the username.\n";
    getline(cin, userinput);
    }
    while (user != userinput);
}
```

It can be seen though, that this only works for a single string variable "user". How would I change this for a string array?

The array itself is the following:

```
string arr[10] = {"Test1", "Test2", "Test3", "Test4", "Test5", "Test6", "Test7", "Test8", "Test9", "Test10"};
```

Please note: I'm not intending to use passwords, only usernames.

Comment: Write a separate function returning a `bool`, that checks for `userinput` parameter in a loop going through this array and use this one as condition in your `while()`.

Comment: Hi, I'm rather inexperienced at C++, would you be able to expand on your suggestion?

Comment: I wrote up an answer. I hope you get the idea.

Comment: You might want to consider using a `std::unordered_set` for the strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the check in a separate function

```
 bool isValidUserName(const string& input) {
      for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
          if(input == arr[i]) {
              return true;
          }
      }
      return false;
 }
```

and use it as condition in the while

```
 while (!isValidUserName(userinput));
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It seems to only validate the first element of the array though, and denies any other username after the first?

Comment: @HarryLudlow No it compares every element from the array with the given input parameter.

Comment: Strange. It would only accept the Test1 and not Test2 (or any other), but when in the array I swapped them around, only Test 2 worked.

Comment: @HarryLudlow I assumed your array is globally defined. How are you actually using the function?

Comment: I've moved the array up to outside main() because when I used the function inside main() it naturally gave an error. They're both now before the line int main() {.

Comment: @HarryLudlow Then I don't see a reason why it shouldn't work, unless you (or me) have made a typo somewhere (can't actually spot one from my side).

Comment: @HarryLudlow I've made up a [working sample](http://ideone.com/df2U8z), you problem is probably, you had missed to apply the check for the first input made.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the built-in [`count`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) function like so:

```
do{
    getline(cin, userinput);
}
while(!std::count(arr, arr+10, userinput));
```

On [ideone](http://ideone.com/alIeL4) as well.

This is how your loop should look:

```
cout << "Please enter your identity.\n"; //Identify user
getline(cin, userinput);
while (!std::count(arr, arr+10, userinput)) //Check to see if user is the same as the string variable "user"
{
    cout << "This user is either non existent or has access privileges revoked.\n"; //Wrong username!
    cout << "Please re-enter the username.\n";
    getline(cin, userinput);
}
```

You can see it [here](http://ideone.com/If2JBt).

Comment: I'm getting a 'count' is not a member of 'std' - I am using namespace std, if that helps?

Comment: You probably forgot the `#include <algorithm>` (just click on the ideone link) :) (BTW using `using namespace std;` is [not recommended](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721).)

Comment: Ahh, that would explain it! Sorry, just getting to grips with C++. Yeah, I know that it's not really a good idea to use it, but I'll change it once I've cracked this :D

Comment: @HarryLudlow Glad to help, do tell if you have any further problems with this solution.

Comment: Interestingly enough, I do! It seems the first time I input a string which is in the array, it denies it, then accepts the exact same input the second time round! (Sorry to be a PITA!)

Comment: @HarryLudlow that's because you had a getline before the `do-while` so it did not check the condition. I've pasted a minimal refactoring proposal that works...

Comment: *doh*! I just realised that as I worked to test the other solution!

Comment: @HarryLudlow Glad it works, BTW using standard built-in functions is a better practice, save your typing effort for the interesting parts :)

Comment: I see. Much thanks to you; I wish I could give two accepted answers but I'll have to select the other. I shall bear your improvements in mind though!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a big number of strings to compare, then it will be much more efficiently to use a hash map (`std::unordered_set`) instead of an array. Search in a hash table is much faster then in an array.

```
unordered_set<string> valid_inputs {"Test1", "Test2", "Test3", "Test4", "Test5", "Test6"};
```

Then you can check an user input in such a way:

```
if (valid_inputs.find(user_input) == valid_inputs.end())
  cout << "error";
else
  cout << "success";
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I'll try both methods I think and get a feel for the different approaches!